# Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to call a field and it's heading on a post type. I want to call headings only if there is content in the field. I'm really new to PHP and am unsure how it all works. I have added the following script in content-single.php

```
 <?php $field = get_field('introduction'); 
    if(!empty && is_array){
        ?>
         <div class="sc-project-type">
            <h4>Introduction:</h4>
            <?php //$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'project_type');
                echo '$field'; ?>
         </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

This brakes produces nothing. If I just , it works, but I want to add lots of fields that won't always be visible. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is very broken. `empty()` and `is_array()` are both functions but you've left off the parens and the arguments. If you have [debugging enabled](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983?s=1|3.2122#95983) you'd probably see warnings about undefined constants. At any rate, it won't work as you need it to.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after playing for a while, I solved my issue with the following code:

```
        <?php $field = get_field('introduction');
    if(!empty ($field)){
        ?>
         <div class="sc-project-type">
            <h4>Introduction:</h4>
            <?php echo ($field); ?>
         </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What are you doing exactly ? Just remove a comment line ?