# WP Database Table to CSV file

Tags: database, wpdb

I'm working on creating a script that takes a custom WordPress database table and exports it into a CSV file. I cannot seem to get it to work. Can someone help me out

```
<?php
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-admin', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_email_table;");
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $row) {
$csv_output .= $row->Field.
$i++;
}
$csv_output .= "\n";

$values = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_email_table;");
foreach ($values as $rowr) {    
for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
$csv_output .= $rowr->$j.
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
}

$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
exit;
?>
```

OK, so i modified it some more and now i receive the following error

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array on line 8

Comment: Please check [this link](https://gist.github.com/umairidrees/8952054#file-php-save-db-table-as-csv) and [this link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/export-wordpress-db-table-to-excel) either of it shall give you a solution.

Comment: Thanks @ItsMePN, i have tried the 2 links that you have provided and I still cannot get it to work. I have updated the code to reflect the changes but im still getting errors.

Comment: `$result` vs. `$results`...

Comment: Thanks @jgraup i have corrected this (i updated the code here) and I get a completely different error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: I updated @jgraup but something tells me i didnt do it correctly. Can you let me know what I did wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33491/discussion-between-phantom-and-jgraup).

Answer (score 3):

You've got a few things wrong.

1. The first is that you are clearly in WordPress context. You should
   be using the AJAX API for this rather than including `wp-load.php`.
   That is virtually never the right way to do it.
2. `get_results()` defaults to an object, so you are going to get
   errors when you try to use the results as an array. Add `ARRAY_A` to
   the argument list for that function (or use object syntax)
3. Don't hard-code the WordPress table prefix
4. `$file` isn't defined
5. You have two queries when you only need one
6. Your `foreach` and `for`, and associated code, is far too
   complicated.

I don't have your table to test with but this should be close.

```
function csv_pull_wpse_212972() {
  global $wpdb;
  $file = 'email_csv'; // ?? not defined in original code
  $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}email_table;",ARRAY_A);

  if (empty($results)) {
    return;
  }

  $csv_output = '"'.implode('";"',array_keys($results[0])).'";'."\n";;

  foreach ($results as $row) {
    $csv_output .= '"'.implode('";"',$row).'";'."\n";
  }
  $csv_output .= "\n";

  $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
  header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
  header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
  header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
  print $csv_output;
  exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_csv_pull','csv_pull_wpse_212972');
```

To "trigger" this send a request to `http://sitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=csv_pull`. Within WordPress you can generate that (and should generate that) with `$ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=csv_pull');`

Comment: Thanks @s_ha_dum that has gotten me close. Currently i get Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by... warning. Followed by a printed version of the CSV information. What I ultimately needed is to be able to call this function on button click to start a download of the CSV file.How can this be accomplished?

Comment: hmm... I don't see anything that should cause that, and I got no errors in testing. [Enable debugging](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983?s=1|3.2132#95983) (if you haven't) and see what you turn up. It may be some other code causing that issue. A number of hooks fire on `admin-ajax.php`

Comment: Yes I will take a look at that. In the meantime can you tell me how I would initiate the download on button click?

Comment: @Phantom : see the edit