# get_the_terms is not working

Tags: database, updates, terms

After I updated WordPress, a function using `get_the_terms()` is not working.

When I run `get_the_terms()` I'm not getting `terms`, but when I add before that call `wp_cache_flush();` I'm getting `terms` so there are probably some problems with permissions.

I've also deactivated all `plugins` (*including `super cache`*) but that did not help/change any.

Can somebody help me?

**UPDATE**
I found out that there is a database problem. As long I use the old database everything is working correctly, but after WordPress asked me to update the database the problem starts.

Comment: Whelp, WordPress recently added `term_meta`, can you edit your question and paste in the `get_the_terms()` function?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - sorry I don't understand you

Comment: Turn on [debugging](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376) and [edit] relevant information into the question.

Comment: this was production site so I've downgraded version :(