# cron job to auto delete posts of a specific post type older than x days

Tags: query, sql, cron, bulk

I want to delete all posts of a specific post type (in this case "vfb_entry") that are older than 60 days. The cron job should run once a day.

I have the following code but it's not working if I trigger the cron job. However, running only the query in phpMyAdmin returns the correct result. So there must be an issue with the fuction itself.

Can anyone please help?

```
// Cron Job to Delete VFB Entries older than 60 days
if(!wp_next_scheduled( 'remove_old_vfb_entries')){
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'remove_old_vfb_entries');
}
add_action('remove_old_vfb_entries', 'myd_remove_old_vfb_entries');

// Build the function
function myd_remove_old_vfb_entries(){
global $wpdb;
// Set max post date and post_type name
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-60 days'));
$post_type = 'vfb_entry';

// Build the query 
// Only select VFB Entries from LFG or LFM Form
$query = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts 
    WHERE post_type = '$post_type' 
    AND post_status = 'publish' 
    AND post_date < '$date'
    AND ($wpdb->posts.ID IN (SELECT entry_id FROM wp_postmeta_lfg4 WHERE post_id IS NOT NULL) OR $wpdb->posts.ID IN (SELECT entry_id FROM wp_postmeta_lfm3 WHERE post_id IS NOT NULL))
    ORDER BY post_modified DESC
";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
            foreach($results as $post){
                // Let the WordPress API clean up the entire post trails
                wp_delete_post( $post->ID, true);
          }
}
```

**Edit:** Solution without querying my views, just using wp_posts and wp_postmeta and an INNER JOIN below.

Comment: Are you sure the `wp_cron()` job fires at all? Have you checked the server logs? Do you [have debugging](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376) enabled (logged to a file would be best in this case)? Why are you not using `WP_Query`? There is no reason at all I can see to order that result set. That part is a waste of resources.

Comment: I used this code because I found it as a snippet on the web. I'm not a programer. I just tried to amend where necessary. But the cron job must have been fired, since I used a plugin to fire it and it said, the cron job was successfully triggered.  So I remove the ordering, but what do you mean by using WP_Query? Please help.

Comment: How about the debugging logs?

Comment: I just checked the log and there's an issue in the sql query. The point is, I needed to create a database view in order to filter the correct vfb_entries, since I do only want to delete specific ones. But it seems WP can't access database views.

Comment: I don't know about WordPress and views. I've never tried but our query above isn't a "view", nor do I really see why you'd need one to do this. Exactly what is the error, word for word?

Comment: I'm so stupid. I pasted the wrong code. I have updated it. The whole story is: The contact form plugin I'm using is saving the entries to the database. I want to delete them if they are older than 60 days. But not all of them, only entries of specific forms. Since the form_id is stored as a meta_key value in wp_postmeta, I created a database VIEW to run a check like "when the post_id is in the VIEW, then it must be from the form of which I want to delete the entries". When I run the whole thing without the last AND, it works fine. So there must be a problem with WP accessing database VIEWs.

Comment: I don't know what a "database VIEW" is but your SQL is wrong. For example, you are trying to seclect the entry_id field from postmeta table, but [that field doesn't exist in that table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description). As suggested by s_ha_dum, you should try to use [WP_Query to get the posts you want](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). I think you will be very happy after learnign `WP_Query`.

Comment: I got it working! Querying the VIEWs with $wpdb->postmeta_lfg4 does not work, but just writing the full name wp_postmeta_lfg4 works! Thank you s_ha_dum for your time. Wouldn't have thought about it if you haven't asked.

Comment: Is it work? Sorry but I think it can not work correctly, as I said your SQL statement is wrong. You may think it works for a while until you get unexpected results. Even the name of the tamble (`wp_postmeta_lfg4`) seems wrong and of course the use of `$wpdb->postmeta_lfg4`, there is not `postmeta_lfg4` property in WPDB class.

Comment: A database view is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL) and my view is called wp_postmeta_lfg4. As it is not part of the WPDB class it didn't work. Now with its full name it does work. EDIT: Okay, it's not working. :(

Comment: Found a different solution without querying my views. See first post.

Comment: Please do not edit the solution into the question. That is what the "answer" box is for.

Answer (score 3):

```
// add the schedule event if it has been removed 
if( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'mg_remove_old_entries' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'mg_remove_old_entries' ); //run the event daily
}

// action hooked to fired with wordpress cron job
add_action( 'mg_remove_old_entries', 'mg_remove_old_entries' );
function mg_remove_old_entries() {
  $posts = get_posts( [
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'vfb_entry',
    'date_query' => [
      // get all the posts from the database which are older than 60 days
      'before' => date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( '-60 days' ) ),
    ],
  ]);

  if( !empty($posts) ) {
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
      wp_delete_post( $post->ID ); //remove the post from the database
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** There is no need to run any custom sql query. It would make the query slow and also it is not good for wordpress. Wordpress has already in built functions for everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Cron Job to Delete VFB Entries older than 60 days
if(!wp_next_scheduled( 'remove_old_vfb_entries')){
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'remove_old_vfb_entries');
}
add_action('remove_old_vfb_entries', 'myd_remove_old_vfb_entries');

// Build the function
function myd_remove_old_vfb_entries(){
global $wpdb;
// Set max post date and post_type name
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-60 days'));
$post_type = 'vfb_entry';

// Build the query 
// Only Delete Entries from Form 5 and 8
$query = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts 
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta 
      ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    WHERE post_type = '$post_type' 
    AND post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_vfb_form_id' 
    AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 5 OR $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 8) 
    AND post_date < '$date' 
";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
            foreach($results as $post){
                // Let the WordPress API clean up the entire post trails
                wp_delete_post( $post->ID, true);
          }
}
```

Comment: What is this? An answer? If so, please explain it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to delete all posts of a specific post type (in this case "vfb_entry") that are older than 60 days. The cron job should run once a day.

The first step is setting up the cron job. The code in the question is correct for this part, so it's basically copied below.

The second part requires querying the database for a specific post type where the entry is older than 60 days. We can do this with `get_posts()` and specifying the `post_type` argument and the `date_query` argument.

```
//* If the scheduled event got removed from the cron schedule, re-add it
if( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'wpse_213720_remove_old_entries' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'wpse_213720_remove_old_entries' );
}

//* Add action to hook fired by cron event
add_action( 'wpse_213720_remove_old_entries', 'wpse_213720_remove_old_entries' );
function wpse_213720_remove_old_entries() {
  //* Get all the custom post type entries older than 60 days...
  $posts = get_posts( [
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'wpse_262471_post_type',
    'date_query' => [
      'before' => date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( '-60 days' ) ),
    ],
  ]);
  //* ...and delete them
  array_filter( function( $post ) {
    wp_delete_post( $post->ID );
  }, $posts );
}
```

The answer above directly queries `$wpdb`. Using the `get_posts()` abstraction is better for a variety of reasons including ease-of-reading and future-proofing.