# When using shortcode, content stops generating after the_content

Tags: php, shortcode, get-template-part

Yesterday I implemented a shortcode, but now my comments and related posts stop appearing.

The source of a rendered page now only displays

```
            <div class="posts-group">
            </div>
```

instead of

```
    <div class="posts-group">          
      <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="posts-group"><h2>Looking for more articles?</h2>
       //RELATED POSTS
    </div>
```

Now the only difference is the use of the shortcode, so the "bug" has to be there, right?
Only problem is.. I see nothing wrong with it.

shortcode in functions.php:

```
function get_products($atts) {
  ob_start();
  get_template_part('block-products-inline');
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('products', 'get_products');
```

the block-products-inline template part:

```
<br>    
    <p><i>Article continues below these four featured products!</i></p>

    <div class="posts-group inline-products">

        <h1>Featured store products</h1>

            <?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'post_type=product&posts_per_page=4&orderby=rand' );
            while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
            ?>

            <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'PRODUCT-url', true);?>">
                <article class="post home-post homeproduct">
                        <div class="post-thumbnail-img inline-products-hover">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <h2>
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </h2>
            </a>        
                        <p>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </p>
                </article>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
<br>
```

I'm hoping someone else sees/finds my problem as I haven't got a clue.

Comment: Where is `block-products-inline.php`? What is the full path? Where are you using the shortcode? Is it inside the post content as typical?

Comment: block-products-inline.php is in the root theme folder, shortcode is used inside the post content

Comment: [Are you getting any errors?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983?s=1|3.2134#95983)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, but you are running a secondary query inside the Loop (by way of the shortcode). That is going to alter some variables that subsequent code may depend upon, such as `$post`.

I am thinking that you need to add [`wp_reset_query();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) after your secondary Loop in the shortcode-- right after the `endwhile;`